# Connect to Oracle 19C Cloud from sqlplus

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I am not able to connect to my Oracle 19C Cloud DB, I have downloaded the wallet and placed it in a secured place in my machine(windows).
I have installed Oracle 19C Client in my machine,
and updated tnsnames.ora(network/admin)  with connection strings from wallet zip,
Not sure how whether I have missed any config like Environment variables
Getting below error from sqlplus
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Note: I am able to connect to Cloud from Sql developer using the wallet file.
And I have Oracle 18c XE running in my machine.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to install instant client if you have 18c XE database installed on your machine.Did you set up wallet location directory in sqlnet.ora?.Post your sqlnet.ora file

Comment: Connecting from Sql Developer is easy and straightforward check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/connect-sql-dev.html#GUID-FB611317-2999-4C8C-8A3B-B3B3D3C5B417)

Comment: wallet location in sqlnet.ora of XE directory ?

Comment: Hi @Learner, did you create a new tnsnames.ora  and sqlnet.ora for the wallet ?

Comment: Hi @kumar/ @Roberto, 
I have placed the tns provided by cloud inside XE tns, and updated the wallet location in XE sqlnet.ora, then I was able to connect to cloud DB using SQLPLUS and Node.js
but now I am not able to connect thru my Node.js but SQLPLUS works fine. (note: no changes done to my Node.js code)
Error from Node.js :
[Error: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred] {
  errorNum: 12170,
  offset: 0
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related with the issue that you have an Oracle XE database version installed in your own laptop.

When you run sqlplus or any other OCI tool to connect to Oracle, no matter whether the database is a remote host or in the cloud, sqlplus evaluates the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to identify where your sqlnet and tnsnames files are located. If there is no variable, it uses the default values of your main Oracle registry entries, that for sure point to your XE version, as it was installed before.

When you get **ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified** , your session is not finding any information regarding the target in your configuration files, probably because the session is evaluating the files in your XE installation

Try to do the following

- Copy the wallet files provided by your Oracle Cloud to a location different to your XE installation.
- Export the TNS_ADMIN variable in your sqlplus cmd session to this new path
- Run sqlplus using wallet

Example ( I believe you did points 1 and 2 )

1. Install Oracle Client software on your computer. Use either the full
   Oracle Database Client 11.2.0.4 (or higher) or the Oracle Instant
   Client 12.1.0.2 (or higher). The Instant Client contains the minimal
   software needed to make an Oracle Call Interface connection. The
   Instant Client 12.1.0.2 (or higher) is sufficient for most
   applications.
2. Download client credentials and store the file in a secure folder on
   your client computer. See Download Client Credentials (Wallets).
3. Unzip/uncompress the credentials file into a secure folder on your client computer.
4. Edit the sqlnet.ora file in the folder where you unzip the
   credentials file, **replacing "?/network/admin" with the name of the
   folder containing the client credentials**.

Example

```
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = file) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY="/my_new_path")))
SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=yes

cmd> set tns_admin = my_new_path
cmd> sqlplus /@yourtnsentry
```

I don't know whether your cloud database is using a Public IP address or not, or if you want to use SSH tunneling to connect to the database. Take a look here, because then you might want to use SQLcl ( Sql Developer Command Line )

https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Database/Tasks/connectingDB.htm